# Windows 10 calculator app does not respect region format decimal symbol

Tags: windows, microsoft-excel, locale, calculator

I recently installed Windows 10 (upgrade from 7). It is an English version Windows, which I configured to the German locale(*), which uses a comma (",") instead of a dot (".") as the decimal separator, i.e. the number Pi is 3,14 not 3.14.

This works fine in Excel. However, it does NOT in the standard Windows calculator, which simply IGNORES a comma key press COMPLETELY. If I use a dot, it produces a dot which works as a decimal separator (which is wrong).

Note that I'm talking about the actual comma key here, not the numpad comma, which works fine but produces a dot in the Calculator (it produces a comma in Excel!).

**My question**: Does anyone have any ideas how to get Calculator to respect the German locale and recognize the comma key and display a comma?

(*) Control Panel > Change date, time, or number formats > Format: German (Germany). Under additional settings, the decimal separator is correctly set to ",".

Comment: It sounds like the calculator does not have that functionality.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To answer my own question: **This is a bug in the Windows 10 calculator**.

The problem did not exist in Windows 7, and it was NOT fixed in the first big update for Windows 10. As of December 2015, the bug is still there.

As usual there is no official acknowledgement. However, for a discussion on the Microsoft servers, see e.g. https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_7-winapps/windows-calculator-decimal-separator-is-always/d6e80dc7-9738-4a61-8457-c5e5d28beeb8?db=5&auth=1

Answer (score 3):

Control Panel > Region > Additional settings...

Change decimal symbol to comma and it will work as expected. Tried it myself just now and it works like a charm.

Comment: You might want to keep in mind the date this question was asked.

Answer (score 0):

Settings > Time and language > region & language > set as default for English keyboard 
and restart the windows

Comment: Have you tried this yourself? Does this work. Doesn't work for me

Answer (score 0):

As you said yourself, this is a problem with the calculator in Windows 10 that hasn't been fixed yet. What I did to solve this for me was to [install the Windows 7/8 calculator](http://winaero.com/blog/get-calculator-from-windows-8-and-windows-7-in-windows-10/).